# How do I make it so that the equations aren't as far away?

Tags: equations, formatting, align

This is what I currently have:

[image]

[image]

The equations are really far away, how do I make them closer: below is the code for it.

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{4\pi^2}{g} &  = 4.0138  &  \frac{\Delta g}{g} = \frac{\Delta m}{m}
\\ \therefore g & = \frac{4\pi^2}{4.0138} = 9.8357m\:s^{-2} &  \therefore \frac{\Delta g}{9.8357m\:s^{-2}} = \frac{0.2638s^2\:m^{-1}}{4.0243s^2\:m^{-1}}
\end{align*}
\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: $\therefore \Delta g = 0.6447m\:s^{-2}$
```

and

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi^2\:L^2}{3g} &  = 0.3375m\:s^{-2}  &  \frac{\Delta L}{L} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta g}{g} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta c}{c}
\\ \therefore L & = \sqrt{\frac{(0.3375m\:s^{-2})(29.5071m\s^{-2})}{\pi^2}}  &  \therefore \frac{\Delta L}{1.0045} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{0.6430m\:s^{-2}}{9.357m\:s^{-2}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{0.1269m\:s^{-2}}{0.3375m\:s^{-2}}
\end{align*}
\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: = 1.0045m \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$\therefore \Delta L = 0.2217m$`
```

Edit, for @Zarko

Using the method you showed, I was able to add everything up until I said L = 1.0045. Whenever I try to put it in, the formatting gets all messed up again. How do I fix this?

[image]

I'm trying to put L = 1.0045m but the formatting gets messed up.

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi^2\:L^2}{3g} 
    & = 0.3375m\:s^{2}  
        &   \frac{\Delta L}{L} 
            & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta g}{g} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta c}{c}                              \\ 
\therefore L   & = \sqrt{\frac{(0.3375m\:s^{2})(29.5071m\:s^{-2})}{\pi^2}}
        &   \therefore \frac{\Delta L}{1.0045m}
            & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{0.6430m\:s^{-2}}{9.357m\:s^{-2}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{0.1269m\:s^{2}}{0.3375m\:s^{2}}\\
    &   &   \therefore \Delta L
            & = 0.2217m
\end{align*}
```

Comment: You should provide an MWE, which reproduce <our problem and not just two code fragments, for which us bit known how us used in your document. On this ways, is hard to help you.

Comment: start by removing all the `\:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just try to rewrite you first code fragment (mess) to an MWE. May guessing was the following::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{4\pi^2}{g} 
    & = 4.0138  
        &   \frac{\Delta g}{g} 
            & = \frac{\Delta m}{m}                              \\ 
\therefore g   & = \frac{4\pi^2}{4.0138} = \qty{9.8357}{\metre\per\square\second} 
        &   \therefore \frac{\Delta g}
                 {\qty{9.8357}{\metre\per\square\second}} 
            & = \frac{\qty{0.2638}{\square\second\per\metre}}
                     {\qty{4.0243}{\square\second\per\metre}}    \\
    &   &   \therefore \Delta g
            & = \qty{0.6447}{\square\second\per\metre}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As you see, in above MWE I employ two packages:

- `amssymb` for `\therefore` symbol, and
- `siunitx` for correct writing of units used in your fragments

[image]

Is this what you after? If yes, now you have a skeleton how to edited your second code fragment ...

**Addendum:**
I tested your edited second code fragment. From my test follows:

- For units you not use `siunity` syntax. Why? You not like SI standards for quantities notations?
- *Main source of your problem(s) is the fact, that you not provided any information about your document, i.e. about page layout. It is still unknown! So the original answer anticipated default layout determined by `article` document class. Also below enumerated possible remedy is based on this.*
- Aforementioned emphasize why is so important why in the question is provided MWE!
- Equations in the second code fragment are much wider than in the first fragment, consequently distance between left and right column of equation almost vanished and right column spill out of right text border:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

What to do? There are several options:

- reduce font size for those equations (not recommended, result is almost unreadably and typographical very ugly)
- change page layout, for example with employ of the `geometry` package:
- reformat writing of equations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
% document body
\end{document}
```

than result is far better:

[image]

- locally changing `\textwidth` just for this case and by this enable that equation can protrude out of right border without any compilation warnings or bad boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{4\pi^2}{g}
    & = 4.0138
        &   \frac{\Delta g}{g}
            & = \frac{\Delta m}{m}                              \\
\therefore g   & = \frac{4\pi^2}{4.0138} = \qty{9.8357}{\metre\per\square\second}
        &   \therefore \frac{\Delta g}
                 {\qty{9.8357}{\metre\per\square\second}}
            & = \frac{\qty{0.2638}{\square\second\per\metre}}
                     {\qty{4.0243}{\square\second\per\metre}}    \\
    &   &   \therefore \Delta g
            & = \qty{0.6447}{\square\second\per\metre}
\end{align*}
  
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}  % <---
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi^2\:L^2}{3g}
    & = \qty{0.3375}{\metre\per\square\second}
        &   \frac{\Delta L}{L}
            & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta g}{g} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta c}{c}                              \\
\therefore L   & = \sqrt{\frac{(\qty{0.3375}{\metre\per\square\second})
                                    (\qty{29.5071}{\metre\per\square\second})}
                              {\pi^2}}     
        &   \therefore \frac{\Delta L}{\qty{1.0045}{\metre}}
            & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\qty{0.6430}{\metre\per\square\second}}
                                {\qty{9.357}{\metre\per\square\second}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\qty{0.1269}{\metre\per\square\second}}
                                                {\qty{0.3375}{\metre\per\square\second}}\\
    &   &   \therefore \Delta L
            & = \qty{0.2217}{\metre}
\end{align*} 
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- From comparison with the first image in addendum that now spacing  between equations on page is better.
- At the end possible reformatting of the second code fragment:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
% second, edited code fragment
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi^2\:L^2}{3g}
    & = \qty{0.3375}{\metre\per\square\second}
        &   \frac{\Delta L}{L}
            & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta g}{g} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta c}{c}                              \\
\therefore L   & = \sqrt{\frac{\splitfrac{(\qty{0.3375}{\metre\per\square\second})\cdot}
                                         {(\qty{29.5071}{\metre\per\square\second})}}
                              {\pi^2}}
        &   \therefore \frac{\Delta L}{\qty{1.0045}{\metre}}
            & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\qty{0.6430}{\metre\per\square\second}}
                                {\qty{9.357}{\metre\per\square\second}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\qty{0.1269}{\metre\per\square\second}}
                                                {\qty{0.3375}{\metre\per\square\second}}\\
    &   &   \therefore \Delta L
            & = \qty{0.2217}{\metre}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you should decide what of suggested options is the most appropriate in your real document.

Comment: Hi Zarko, thanks so much. I was editing the second one and it was all fine until I got to the part ive edited in the post itself.

Comment: I test your edition of the second code fragment. In addendum I show test results with some ideas what to do.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 2):

(this answer addresses only issue mentioned in the addendum to the OP's query)

I suggest employing an `alignat*{2}` environment. I would further recommend that you start to learn how to use the `\qty` macro provided by the `siunitx` package to typeset quantities and the associated scientific units.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\unit' and '\qty' macros
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\frac{\pi^2\,L^2}{3g}
  &= \qty{0.3375}{\meter\second\squared}  
  &   
\frac{\Delta L}{L} 
  &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta g}{g} 
   + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Delta c}{c} \\
\therefore\ 
L   
  &= \sqrt{\frac{
    (\qty{0.3375}{\meter\second\squared})
    (\qty{29.5071}{\meter\per\second\squared})}{\pi^2}}
  &\qquad  % <-- horiz. distance between notional columns
\therefore\ 
\frac{\Delta L}{\qty{1.0045}{m}}
  &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot
     \frac{\qty{0.6430}{\meter\per\second\squared}}%
          {\qty{9.3570}{\meter\per\second\squared}} + 
     \frac{1}{2}\cdot
     \frac{\qty{0.1269}{\meter\second\squared}}%
          {\qty{0.3375}{\meter\second\squared}} \\
  &&   
\therefore 
\Delta L
  &= \qty{0.2217}{\meter}\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```